# How to change the content rights option in iTunes Connect submission

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, submission

I recently attempted to submit my app for review in iTunes Connect. When being asked "Does your app contain, display, or access third-party content", I accidentally checked 'Yes'.

The app got rejected, I made changes, and submitted a new build, but was not given the option to select if my app uses third-party content or not when submitting it for review.

Not sure how to get back to the prompt, and check 'No'.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to change it? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @user3673952 I haven't been able to. I called Apple Support, but they were not able to help either. When submitting the newest version, I put the issue in the review notes, but no response... so not actually sure if they changed it internally or not.